# Organizing Laravel and autoloading sub directories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am wanting to structure my laravel app in a way that all of my code is under the `src` directory. My project structure would look something like the below. How would I do this where I can still call `Route::get('accounting/item/{id}','AccountingItemController@getId')`

I am wanting to avoid adding every module under src to the ClassLoader. Is there a way to tell the class loader to load all sub-directories under the parent directory src?

```
app
app/src
app/src/accounting
app/src/accounting/controllers
app/src/accounting/models
app/src/accounting/repos
app/src/accounting/interfaces
app/src/job
app/src/job/controllers
app/src/job/models
app/src/job/repos
app/src/job/interfaces
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's called PSR-0.

You should namespace all of your code. Typically you'll have a vendor name that you'll use a the top level namespace. Your application structure should then look something like this.

```
app/src/Vendor/Accounting/Controllers
app/src/Vendor/Job/Controllers
```

Your controllers will then be namespaced accordingly.

```
namespace Vendor\Accounting\Controllers;
```

And when using them in routes.

```
Route::get('accounting/item/{id}','Vendor\Accounting\Controllers\ItemController@getId');
```

Lastly, you can register your namespace with Composer in your `composer.json`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Vendor": "app/src"
    }
}
```

Of course, if you don't want that top level `Vendor` namespace you can remove it, but you'll need to register each component as PSR-0.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Accounting": "app/src",
        "Job": "app/src",
    }
}
```

Once done, run `composer dump-autoload` once and you should be able to add new controllers, models, libraries, etc. Just make sure the directory structure aligns with the namespacing of each file.

Comment: Here is the link from composer's site if one needs to read more on how composer does it https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Answer (score 1):

Do you have composer installed? You should use this:

`composer dump-autoload`

But you can could add directories to the Laravel's classloader. Check the reference here: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.ClassLoader.html

Comment: Yes, and this will work but is there a way to autoload all subdirectories without having to declare them individually? I dont want to have to register each and every directory under /src